# Set $S=\{(x,y,z)| x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subset of vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$, how do I show that it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So I know that set  $S=\{(x,y,z)| x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subset of vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Specifically, it is worded in our lecture that it is a " subset of $(\mathbb{R}^3, \oplus, \odot)$ , where $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are the usual vector addition and scalar multiplication."

My teacher has stated in our lecture that this set $S$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

But from what I can tell $S$ is:

1. Closed under addition
2. Closed under multiplication
3. Contains a zero vector $(0,0,0)$

How is it not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, what am I missing?

Comment: 0.5 times any vector is once again in the set?

Comment: You need to check the definition of a vector subspace, and check each of the things your set needs to satisfy. There is at least one which it clearly doesn't satisfy.

Comment: this is called an integer lattice. For a linear subspace, any real mulitple of a vector must also be in the subspace

Comment: No, 0.5 times any vector  in S would not be within the set anymore. But being closed under  multiplication means that the end result would need to be within R3, not still within S. Am I misunderstanding that? Does the result need to stay within S as well?

Comment: Yes you are misunderstanding that.

Comment: Awesome, thank you I'll reread more on what closed under multiplication means, I see now that it wouldnt satisfy the second condition if that is the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1,0,0)$ belongs to $S$.  Scale this by the real scalar $1/2$ and obtain $(1/2,0,0)$ which is not in $S$.  Hence $S$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

It is not closed under multiplication. 
Take $\lambda=\sqrt{2}$ and any vector $v=(a,b,c)\in S$. Since $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z$ then $a\sqrt{2}, b\sqrt{2}, c\sqrt{2}\notin \Bbb Z$. Then $\lambda\cdot v \notin S$.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: User Randall pointed out that I misread the question. (I assumed S was under some invalid field.)

First lets look at the definition of a subspace:

1. All products and sums composed of elements within the subspace also are in the subspace.
2. All elements in the subspace must be able to be scaled by the vector space surrounding the subspace.
3. 0 is also an element of the subspace.

You remembered rule 1 and 3 however, it's clear S is violating rule 2.

In order for S to be a subset of $R^3$, all elements within S that are scaled by any number within R are also an element of S.

Comment: But point 2 isn't the real problem.  OP is working over the reals, so s/he definitely has inverses of all non-zero scalars.  The problem is that the scalar multiplication is not closed on the potential-subspace $S$.

Comment: @Randall Oh you're right. I misread the question. I'll edit my answer.